# Angular 7 how to specify folder for images in dist

Tags: angular, angular7

When I build project by `ng build` command in `dist` folder I got my `js` files both with all other resources, but I want to move all images and fonts in separate folder like `assets`. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Update: 
angular.json

 `"assets": [
   "src/favicon.ico",
   "src/assets"
],`

in scss of component I have:

`background-image: url('assets/img/no-notifications.svg');`

but in result I got in dist folder next file:

`no-notifications.7e08682a570485d1c108.svg`

Goal is keep image path same as he has been specified in scss file:
 `assets/img/no-notifications.svg`

Answer (score 12):

If you didn't already know, a new option was added into angular cli configuration (since [v7.2.1](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v7.2.1)) to copy css resources into another folder (relative to the output path).

```
"outputPath": "wwwroot",
"resourcesOutputPath": "images"
```

https://angular.io/cli/build

Answer (score 3):

try this

create  `img` folder inside `assets`

and use path like `./assets/img/your_image`

it will work.

Comment: I't doesn't work: I got an error that path can't be resolved, when I use `assets/img/your_image` (without `./` prefix) it's works but files put into root of `dist` folder

Comment: It doesn't work. ng-cli only copies those files referenced, not the full folder or subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

The given solution `"resourcesOutputPath": "images"` works fine for image. But unfortunately if we need to do the same for other resources like `*.js` or `*.ttf` files etc... it will not work.

Here is how I do that for `*.js` files : in the file `package.json`, below the `scripts` node, I add a script called `postbuild` that will :

1. Move the files in the dedicated folder (`resources` in my example)
2. Search and replace `<script src="*.js"></script>` in `index.html` by `<script src="resources/*.js"></script>`. The search and replace is done with `sed` commande line (please be aware that there are some difference with `sed` commande lin on linux or MacOS).

Here is the final look of my `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "postbuild": "mv ./dist/my-project/*.js ./dist/my-project/*.js.map ./dist/my-project/resources; sed -i -e 's/src=\"/src=\"resources\\//g' dist/my-project/index.html",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, using 'ng build' command 'assets' and their 'sub-folders' will be automatically copied to 'dist' folder. If you want to create another folder in the same root level, let say 'resources'.

In angular.json, there is 'assets' configuration where we can define 'src/resources'.

**angular.json**

```
"assets": ["src/resources"],
```

Comment: I've same rule, but it's doesn't solve my problem, angular parse all css files and move all resources into root of output build folder.

Comment: This don't work. ng-cli does not copy the full folder, only those file that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

set "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true in options  of "build" of angular.json